# Why have both CERT and TLSA DNS RR?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I know of at least 2 DNS resource record types that serve the purpose of enabling domain owners the ability to control approved/revoked certificates either self-signed or by CA's namely the `CERT` and `TLSA` RR. I'm not sure if there are other fields that basically do this, but why have both when just one will suffice?

Comment: Those records do not do the same thing. Did you not read their RFCs?

Comment: @MichaelHampton does CERT not store an approved and revoked certificates list? And is the TSLA RR not a record for DANE which basically stores a digest of an approved certificate?

Comment: "enabling domain owners the ability to approve/revoke certificates either self-signed or by CA's" this is certainly not what you can do with a `CERT` record type.

Comment: As Michael said you may want to start by reading the relevant RFCs: 4398 for CERT (that superseded 2538 written in March 1999) and 6698 for core TLSA (august 2012). You can easily see that one just defines a record in the DNS without any specifications on how it can be used, where the other is a full "framework" or ecosystem where the DNS record is just one part of a bigger scheme (called DANE for what is worth).